# Wrap jinja2 block content in intermediate template

Tags: python, jinja2

Is it possible to calla child block from an intermediate parent template?

Example

```
// base.html
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>

// base-for-pages.html
{% block content %}
  <div class="wrap">
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}

// template3.html
{% block content %}
  <h1>Actual content</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

I know it doesn't work like this but is it possible to set up something like in `base-for-pages.html` so that you can wrap the contents of a child template before it's sent to the parent template?

It seems like overkill to create a new root template just to wrap the contents of a child template.

Comment: if template3.html inherits from base-for-pages.html, how about naming that inner block to something else? that should work...

Comment: Yeah, renaming one of the blocks would work -- It just seems like overkill just to wrap contents.